# How to determine ideal period for metricbeat mysql?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, metricbeat

I am trying to configure metricbeat for monitoring mysql server performance. In mysql.yml there is a field called period which determines how frequently metricbeat should check the show global status metrics in mysql. So, the default time is set as 10s. Will this effect mysql server performance specially when the server is very busy with lots of request?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple: you need to try in your own environment and adapt the period to your specific case. The default setting of 10s is a sensible default, it might work for you... or not, it depends!

You need to monitor your MySQL server for a reference period (1 day, 1 week, etc) before starting Metricbeat and then compare the monitoring data after starting Metricbeat and see if Metricbeat is impacting negatively your mySQL server or not.

If that's the case, then you can increase the period and try again, iteratively... There's no magic bullet here.

Comment: most of the time server gets ideal traffic but at the end of the day, it gets lot of traffic. so how can we determine an ideal value in such a case?

Comment: I understand, but trial and error is your best friend here. What Metricbeat does is not terribly expensive either, so I would not worry too much. The `status` metricset simply runs `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` so try that query on peak times and see how long it takes to answer